# Amateur Coder File Testing

Tags: python, file

I am working on a project and have a great idea.
This is a very simple question and I've done this before, but it doesn't seem to be working.
In my idle, when I type:

```
f = open('a.txt', 'w')
f.write('hi')
```

I get an output of 2.
It doesn't make sense to me beyond the fact that hi has a length of two... I want to add 'hi' to my file!!

Comment: Look at write signature, it may be expecting bytes instead of strings. So convert them. Also I have no Idea what programming language you're using. Please specify

Comment: Python -- how would I convert them to bytes instead of strings

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I want to open a text file and and write in it with those commands but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: @AnthonyFarhat `f.close()` the file and look at it?

Comment: Why do you think it's not working?

Comment: The command f.write seems to be doing the wrong thing

Comment: Why do you think it's doing the wrong thing?

Comment: Okay so it turns out it is working BUT it's not changing my opened file, it's saving the file somewhere else

Comment: I apologize for the stupid question, you guys are probably facepalming at this

Comment: Why do you think it's not changing the file you opened?

Comment: because when I open that file it's unchanged

Comment: How sure are you that the file that is unchanged is the file you actually opened?

Comment: Same name no? a.txt

Comment: Are you in the right directory?

Comment: I fixed it - I have no idea what I did but somehow it works. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

you just need to use `f.close()` and the changes will commit

Comment: Why the downvote? Valid answer, f.close() will solve the issue

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: What? Using `f.write("hi")` will not commit changes. It will output the length of the written data to the console. Once `f.close()` has been run, the changes will commit to the file and you will be able to see them, trust me try it - just tried it myself

Comment: OP said "*Okay so it turns out it is working BUT it's not changing my opened file, it's saving the file somewhere else*" so he's probably just confused about which file he's actually writing to.

Comment: Okay seconded, did not see the new comments. Apologies

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the context handler when dealing with fileIO. By using the `with` statement as shown below, the file will automatically close when the codeblock is finished executing.

```
with open('a.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('hi')
```

This saves you from having to remember to close the file when you're done with it.